# DataGridViewCell colors resetting when changing other cell colors (in same row)

Tags: c#, .net

## Background.

I have a `DataGridView`.  When the user sorts a column, the `dataGridView1_Sorted` event is triggered where I give the next cell in a column a different backcolor (if the value is different).

## Problem.

When I sort `column2` (after successfully sorting and changing the colors in `column1`), the coloring of `column1` is changed back to defaults (backcolor is removed/reset to defaults).

If I slow this down and only change a few rows (cells in `column2`), only those rows I changed, have `column1` reset.

```cs
private void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
ColorCodeWaferDataGridView(ref dgv);
}
```

---

## Attempts.

1. Originally I was color coding by creating a new cell style like below, and setting it.

```cs
DataGridView dataGridView1 = dgv; //for simplicity

// Make up the next color
DataGridViewCellStyle changedStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
changedStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
changedStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
changedStyle.Font = dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font;

// Set the row in question to the above color
int row = 1;
string sortedColName = "MyColumn1";
dgv.Rows[row].Cells[sortedColName].Style = changedStyle;
```

2. Then I tried only setting the backcolor, in case there was some default formatting thing getting in the way.

```cs
dgv.Rows[row].Cells[sortedColName].Style.BackColor = changedStyle.BackColor;
```

---

FYI. You have to `.Clone()` a `DataGridViewCellStyle` since each is an instance, and an equal sign just sets the new value to the same reference as the old.

e.g.  You can't do this:

```cs
DataGridViewCellStyle changedStyle_doesntwork = originalStyle;
```

You have to do this:

```cs
DataGridViewCellStyle myNewStyle = originalStyle.Clone();
```

---

3. Putting it all together, this is basically what I have.

```cs
//The triggering event
        private void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
            ColorCodeDataGridView(ref dgv);

        }


//function to change the backcolor (and forecolor if needed)
        private void ColorCodeDataGridView(ref DataGridView dgv)
        {
            string sortedColName = dgv.SortedColumn.Name.ToString();

            // color code the changes
            DataGridViewCellStyle changedStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            changedStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            changedStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            changedStyle.Font = dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font;
            //changedStyle.Font = new Font(changedStyle.Font.FontFamily, changedStyle.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);


            //edgecase
            dgv.Rows[0].Cells[sortedColName].Style = changedStyle;
            for (int row = 1; row < dgv.RowCount; row++)
            {
                //if current row != previous row, change color
                if (dgv.Rows[row].Cells[sortedColName].Value.ToString()
                    != dgv.Rows[row - 1].Cells[sortedColName].Value.ToString())
                {
                    changedStyle = NewChangedStyle2(changedStyle);
                    dgv.Rows[row].Cells[sortedColName].Style.BackColor = changedStyle.BackColor;
                    dgv.Rows[row].Cells[sortedColName].Style.ForeColor = changedStyle.ForeColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    dgv.Rows[row].Cells[sortedColName].Style.BackColor = changedStyle.BackColor;
                }
            }
            dgv.ClearSelection(); //first cell will be blue otherwise
        }


        // gets the 'next color' in the known colors list
        private static DataGridViewCellStyle NewChangedStyle2(DataGridViewCellStyle originalStyle)
        {

            //go down the list of known colors
            int k = (int)originalStyle.BackColor.ToKnownColor();
            DataGridViewCellStyle myNewStyle = originalStyle.Clone();
            myNewStyle.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor((KnownColor)(k + 1));

            //if it is a light background, then make the text dark
            float f = myNewStyle.BackColor.GetBrightness();
            if (f < 0.5)//black
            {
                myNewStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
            else //white
            {
                myNewStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }

            return myNewStyle;
        }
```

Comment: Does sorting the grid over the 2nd column reset the order of the cells in the first column?

Comment: @Moige Yes, sorting the grid over the second column resets the order of the rows, including the first column's cells.

Comment: Well, I'd look into the side effects of that reset then. Shot in the dark but maybe the sorted grid is a different item from your real grid, and the changes to the sorted grid's cell styles don't carry over when a new sort is requested. Not sure why you want them to either.

Comment: That's a good thought.  I can do a partial coloring on `column2` - say rows:1->(n-5). Then rows 1->(n-5) have `column1` coloring reset, but rows (n-4)->n do not have the color reset.  This encapsulates the second sort.

So I don't think it's the re-sort causing the issue.  I feel like it's got to be where I assign the color for a cell because that's where I reference 'row'.

I suppose I could try reading the backcolor for all cells in the row (rather than just the column of interest), then re-write them, plus make the targeted color change.  Let me give it a shot.

Comment: If you don't change the second column's cell styles after the second sort, are the cells of the first column still styled properly? (You should really make sure you got at least one row in your grid before that edge case btw)